# Commit via TortoiseSVN gives ra_local error, Visual Studio commit via AnkhSVN works

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, ankhsvn

I was helping a new coworker commit their changes to our SVN repository via TortoiseSVN, and we had a problem.  The output it gave was:

```
Command: Commit
Error: Commit failed (details follow):
Error: Unable to open an ra_local session to URL
Error: Unable to open repository 'file:///T:'
```

The repository is a file-based repository located in a directory on our T drive.  No one but the admins have write access to the root of T:, but everyone has write access to the **folder** on T: where the repository sits.*

- We tried moving the checked-out copy to another location for the commit. No dice.
- We tried checking out a brand-new copy, manually moving the changes to the new copy, and committing from the new copy. No dice.
- We tried commiting through Visual Studio 2010 via AnkhSVN, and the commit worked fine, which leads me to believe it's an issue related to TortoiseSVN. My coworker has TortoiseSVN 1.6.11 installed on her machine, while I had 1.6.6.  I upgraded to 1.6.11, but was able to commit changes to the same repository without error.

So the question is, why does my coworker's TortoiseSVN fail to commit, and how can we fix it so that it is usable?

* Yes, I know a file-based SVN repo is bad, but unless switching to an SVN server will fix the problem we're having, that's outside the scope of this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks to be the problem described by this changelog entry:

> ```
> * ra_local: fix error with repository in Windows drive root (r1518184)
> ```

This was fixed in Subversion 1.7.14 and 1.8.4.  I'm not sure version of ankhSVN you're using but it might include the fix.

Looking at the tests for that fix you might want to try file:///T:/ for the path to the repo instead.

Fair warning: Upgrade to 1.7 or 1.8 clients will mean that you will have to upgrade your working copies and 1.6 clients won't be able to read them.  This has no impact on your ability to read your repository that you're accessing over ra_local via 1.6 clients.

Comment: Even though we were able to fix this before reading your answer by downgrading my coworker's TortoiseSVN to 1.6.6, you dug around to find the (probable?) cause and deserve the rep.  Thanks!